# Questions about J9

Tags: android, heap-memory, arithmetic-expressions

-Is it true that OpenJ9 has non overflow and underflow arithmetic
modes for float and double?  What needs to be done to obtain that?
If not, can this be changed somehow?

-Is OpenJ9 a compiler or a runtime or both?

-Is OpenJ9 Windows compatible and 64 bit compatible?
Is it Windows or Android smartphone compatible?  Will there be smartphone
versions of OpenJ9 done?

-What is the default memory size before the -Xmx command?  Is there
a way to put the -Xmx command inside the manifest file, and if so, how?
Could I have an example if possible?

Answer (score 2):

For an explanation of OpenJ9 see https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/oj9_faq.html

OpenJ9 will support Windows and 64 bit, but there are some known problems at the moment you can find in the OpenJ9 Issues https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues. There are no current plans for a smartphone port. Instructions for building Java 9 are available https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/blob/master/buildenv/Build_Instructions_V9.md and instructions for Java 8 will be similarly available, see https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/845.

The -Xmx default is different for Java 8 and Java 9 or later, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.80.doc/diag/appendixes/defaults.html and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_9.0.0/com.ibm.java.multiplatform.90.doc/diag/appendixes/defaults.html

For adding -Xmx into a manifest, see IBM-Java-Options in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.80.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/cmdline_specifying.html